# beautifulsoup 4 + python: string returns 'None'

Tags: python, parsing, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse some html with BeautifulSoup4 and Python 2.7.6, but the string is returning "None". The HTML i'm trying to parse is:

```
<div class="booker-booking">
    2&nbsp;rooms
    &#0183;
    USD&nbsp;0
    <!-- Commission: USD  -->
</div>
```

The snippet from python I have is:

```
 data = soup.find('div', class_='booker-booking').string
```

I've also tried the following two:

```
data = soup.find('div', class_='booker-booking').text
data = soup.find('div', class_='booker-booking').contents[0]
```

Which both return:

```
u'\n\t\t2\xa0rooms \n\t\t\xb7\n\t\tUSD\xa00\n\t\t\n
```

I'm ultimately trying to get the first line into a variable just saying "2 Rooms", and the third line into another variable just saying "USD 0".

Comment: is there supposed to be a '_' after 'class'? also, I don't see any 'None' being returned here...

Comment: yes. it's how beautifulsoup identifies the DIV class, rather than python thinking it's a python class.

Comment: what about soup.find("div", {"class": "booker-booking"})?

Comment: returns 'None' as well.

Comment: but you say they return u'\n\t\t2\xa0rooms \n\t\t\xb7\n\t\tUSD\xa00\n\t\t\n', which is a unicode string...

Comment: that is using the .text or .contents[0] attributes instead of .string. but they include all the extra characters (regular expressions, it looks like?) that i don't need. unless there is a way to strip them out?

Comment: perhaps try converting the unicode string to a str with str() then you could try calling strip() on that string. ex: str.strip() removes leading and trailing white space aswell as '\n' newline chars.

Comment: those aren't part of a regular expression, '\n' is simply the newline character and '\t' is a tab.

Comment: when doing that, i get the error: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.string` returns `None` because the text node is not the only child (there is a comment).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
div = soup.find('div', 'booker-booking')
# remove comments
text = " ".join(div.find_all(text=lambda t: not isinstance(t, Comment)))
# -> u'\n    2\xa0rooms\n    \xb7\n    USD\xa00\n     \n'
```

To remove Unicode whitespace:

```
text = " ".join(text.split())
# -> u'2 rooms \xb7 USD 0'
print text
# -> 2 rooms · USD 0
```

To get your final variables:

```
var1, var2 = [s.strip() for s in text.split(u"\xb7")]
# -> u'2 rooms', u'USD 0'
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have done `data = soup.find('div', class_='booker-booking').text` you've extracted the data you need from the HTML. Now you just need to format it to get "2 Rooms" and "USD 0. The first step is probably splitting the data by line:

```
import string
lines = string.split(data, '\n')
```

Which will give `[u'', u'\t\t2\xa0rooms ', u'\t\t\xb7', u'\t\tUSD\xa00', u'\t\t', u'']`

Now you need to get rid of the whitespace, unescape the html characters, and remove the lines that don't have data:

```
import HTMLParser
h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
formatted_lines =  [string.strip(h.unescape(line)) for line in lines if len(line) > 3]
```

You will be left with the data you want:

```
print formatted_lines[0]
#2 rooms
print formatted_lines[1]
#USD 0
```