# BeautifulSoup4 missing elements?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

**Summary**: BS4 isn't picking up the contents of some td elements, returning None instead of the test they contain. I can't figure out why.

**Detail**: I'm trying to scrape an HTML table using BS3 (code below). The table has three columns, like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>From Number</td>
  <td>Time</td>
  <td class="span10" style="word-wrap: break-word;">Message</td>
</tr>
```

(These are actually the col headers; included for context.)

Generally the function below parses each row to:

```
[u'From Number', u' ', u'Time', u' ', u'Message']
```

But sometimes the last element comes out as None:

```
[u'From Number', u' ', u'Time', u' ', None]
```

I thought 
 tags, and then newline characters were causing this, but the problem persists with both stripped out.

```
def grab_smss(soup):   # soup = the web page, parsed after applying
    """                # html_doc = html_doc.replace("\n", "")
    Extracts SMSs from page, in form [From, Ago, Msg]
    """
    sms_list = []
    in_smss = False
    brs = soup.findAll(name="br")   # Removes <br /> tags; looked 
    [br.extract() for br in brs]    # like these were the problem
    for row in soup.body.table.find_all('tr'):
        sms_row = [unicode(child.string) for child in row.children]
        sms_list.append(sms_row)
        if "From Number" in sms_row:
            in_smss = True
    return sms_list
```

Here are some sample problem rows (verbatim, before stripping br tags and \n), and results of the function for those rows:

```
<tr><td>1562375XXXX</td><td>2 minutes ago</td><td class="span10" style="word-wrap: break-word;">1234567: hi honney, trust trying how to use globfone. glad u told me about this site. it will be<br />
useful to me in the future. /check globfone.com<br /></td></tr>
```

Gives: `[u'1562375XXXX', u'26 minutes ago', u'None']`

```
<tr><td>1360234XXXX</td><td>2 hours ago</td><td class="span10" style="word-wrap: break-word;">Your code is: 1083 Enter this code to verify your mobile phone number. The code is valid for 24<br />
hours.</td></tr>
```

Gives: `[u'1360234XXXX', u'3 hours ago', u'None']`

What could be causing this problem.

Comment: The list comprehension to remove the `<br>` tags is wrong it should be `[s.extract() for s in soup('br')]`. Also if you use `child.text` instead of `child.string`, It seems to work. The exception being that the `<br>` tags are replaced by nothing so there are not spaces between some words.

Comment: Using `child.text` I get: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Ok maybe my code is slightly different. I can post the full code that worked for me.

Comment: That'd be great thanks!

Comment: I see you've realised you are using BeautifulSoup 4:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''<html><body><table><tr><td>1562375XXXX</td><td>2 minutes ago</td><td class="span10" style="word-wrap: break-word;">1234567: hi honney, trust trying how to use globfone. glad u told me about this site. it will be<br />
useful to me in the future. /check globfone.com<br /></td></tr></table></body></table>'''

def grab_smss(soup):   # soup = the web page, parsed after applying
    """                # html_doc = html_doc.replace("\n", "")
    Extracts SMSs from page, in form [From, Ago, Msg]
    """
    sms_list = []
    in_smss = False
    [s.extract() for s in soup('br')]
    for row in soup.body.table.find_all('tr'):
        sms_row = [' '.join(unicode(subchild.string) for subchild in child) for child in row.children]
        sms_list.append(sms_row)
        if "From Number" in sms_row:
            in_smss = True
    return sms_list


print grab_smss(BeautifulSoup(data))
```

As a result of the `<br>` tags (even when removed) the child text for the 3rd element is a collection of elements, hence `child.string` returns None. If you iterate over them and join them into a single string it works.

Comment: Ok - I discovered another way to get this working: changing  `sms_row = [unicode(child.string) for child in row.children]` to `sms_row = [unicode(td.text) for td in row.findAll('td')]`, but hadn't figured out why the first version didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: That might actually be more natural syntax and avoids the double loop. I thought I tried something like that actually but mustn't have got it quite right.

Comment: BTW - how did you figure out the child text for the 3rd element remained a collection of elements after stripping the brs? It never occurred to me... (obviously!)

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750852/beautifulsoup-4-python-string-returns-none) question. If you go and print each string individually you can see it becomes None as soon as you try to access `child.string`.